# Do React hooks need to return a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I've recently started to build out custom hooks in my React application and have been following the documentation on the React website. However, the hooks which I am building require no return value as they set up data for Redux on initialization.

Example:

```
// custom hook
export const useSetup() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) fetch().then(data => dispatch(setInit(data)))
  }, [dispatch])
}


// functional component
export function Details() {
  useSetup()
```

I can't find documentation explicitly stating that a hook needs to return anything. However, I cannot find an example of a hook not returning something. Can someone advise on if this approach is correct?

Comment: are you trying to implement redux with react hooks?

Comment: is it possible that hook not fetch because of `if (data)`?

Comment: If a hook *needs* to return anything it is generally documented. `useEffect` is a great example of a hook that might not return anything (*if it does it is an effect cleanup function*). Hooks can return whatever is necessary/needed/etc... They are just functions (*with some rules around usage*) after all.

Comment: should probably use useReducer for implementing a redux like state management system

Comment: @DrewReese right! Okay, thanks for clearing that up for me. Now that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, your approach is correct. React hooks are not required to return anything. The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) states that:

> We don’t have to return a named function from the effect. We called it
> cleanup here to clarify its purpose, but you could return an arrow
> function or call it something different.

The return value of a function that is passed as an argument to a hook has a special use in the lifecycle of the React component it belongs to. Essentially, that return value is expected to be a function and executes before the component with the hook re-renders or is unmounted. React documentation call this kind of hook an "effect with cleanup."

The React documentation uses the example below to show what a `useEffect` hook looks like:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
useEffect(() => {
  // Update the document title using the browser API
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
});
```

As you can see, the anonymous function that is used as an argument to `useEffect` does not have a `return` statement.

You can verify this by changing the function a little bit to log the return value:

```js
const count = 0;

const a = () => {
  // Update the document title using the browser API
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}

console.log(a());
```

This prints `undefined`.

You can also use `console.log` on the `useEffect` function to see that it also returns `undefined`.

If you changed the hook to this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Update the document title using the browser API
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  return () => {
    console.log('cleanup');
  }
});
```

You would see the `"cleanup"` message every time the component re-renders or is unmounted. You would have to trigger the re-render by updating the state of the component in some way.