# How to move useEffect from component to custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple components with the same useEffect code.

```
fucntion MyComponent1 (props) {

 const {
        handleApiCall,
        data,
        isLoading,
        isError,
        isSuccess,
  } = useCustomAsyncHook();

 React.useEffect(() => {
   if (isSuccess && !isEmpty(data)) {
      setSnackbar({
        show: false,
        message: '',
      });
      dispatch({
        type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_METADATA,
        payload: { data },
      });
    }
 }, [data, isSuccess, setSnackbar]);

 const onSave = () => {
     handleApiCall()
 }

 return (
   <button onClick={onSave}> Save </button>
 )

}
```

I have this `useEffect` hook code repeating in multiple components.
I just want to move this useEffect hook into custom hook so that I need not repeat it in multiple components.

```
const useMetadataUpdate = ({ data, isSuccess, setSnackbar, dispatch }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isSuccess && !isEmpty(data)) {
            setSnackbar({
                show: false,
                message: '',
            });
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_METADATA,
                payload: { data },
            });
        }
    }, [data, isSuccess, setSnackbar, dispatch]);
};

fucntion MyComponet1 (props) {
   const {
        handleApiCall,
        data,
        isLoading,
        isError,
        isSuccess,
  } = useCustomAsyncHook();

  useMetadataUpdate({ data, isSuccess, setSnackbar, dispatch });

  const onSave = () => {
     handleApiCall()
 }

 return (
   <button onClick={onSave}> Save </button>
 ) 
}
```

Refactoring `useEffect` to a separate function works.
I can't find documentation explicitly stating a hook needs to return anything, however, I cannot find an example of a hook not returning something. Can someone advise on if this approach is correct?

Comment: You just refactor it into a function, there's nothing special to it.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: @AKX Along with useEffect ? Just like as it is now?

Comment: Well, you will likely need to also move the `isSuccess`, `data`, and `setSnackbar` state and setters along with it, into a custom React hook. If you need more help then we'll need a bit more context around the component this hook is used in.

Comment: @DrewReese Got it. Thanks. its working as expected

Comment: @DrewReese, I make an api call using a custom hook called useAsync which returns isSuccess and data. I need to update my local state from the api response.

Comment: @DrewReese My actual doubt is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148155/do-react-hooks-need-to-return-a-value

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what the doubt is. Are you trying to return a value from your new custom hook?

Comment: @AKX, Is the refactor correct?

Comment: @DrewReese, Updated question with more details. Let me know if you understood my doubt.

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni If you always use the same hook in tandem with `useCustomAsyncHook`, I'd bundle them into the same hook...

Comment: @AKX, Got it. Will make the change. But what about custom hook not returning anything ? Is it correct approach.

Comment: If you don't need to use any data from the hook, then you don't need to return anything.

Comment: I still don't understand what your doubt is, but it sounds like you are still asking about React hooks returning a value. Did you *read* my comment in that other SO post you shared? Hooks only return values when they need to. Think about how `useState` hook works, it returns a state object and a function to update it, while `useEffect` returns nothing. React does a good job of [documenting](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) any hook return values.

Answer (score 3):

To clean up your component, you can move `useEffect` to a custom hook that contains the same logic as the original.

For example

```js
// useCodeSelection.js
...
export const useCodeSelection = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useCodeSelection')
    }
}
...
```

Then inside your component just call it after you import it, like:

```js
...
useCodeSelection()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The current issue as I can see here is that you have 3 functions namely `isEmpty`, `setSnackbar`, and `dispatch` tightly coupled to your components here. This restricts you from directly moving this `useEffect` to your custom hook. The best solution that I can think of right now is moving these functions to a custom hook(you can combine this with context API as well). After that, you can do the following in your custom hook

```
const useCustomAsyncHook = () => {
  // code to fetch dependenices like `data`, `isSuccess` goes here

  const { setSnackbar, isEmpty, dispatch } = useAnotherCustomHook();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSuccess && !isEmpty(data)) {
       setSnackbar({
         show: false,
         message: '',
       });
       dispatch({
         type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_METADATA,
         payload: { data },
       });
     }
  }, [data, isSuccess, setSnackbar]);
};
```